# Iterate each character in Word documents

Tags: vba, ms-word, interop, character

I need to iterate each character in any given word document. I am somewhat familiar with the object model but couldn't figure out how to get this granular.

Any approach will work (Macro, Interop, AddIn or OLE Embedding).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is wrong with

```
For Each ch In ActiveDocument.Characters
```

?

Answer (score 0):

A manual approach to that, would be this: I am sure it works for 'normal' documents, as long as the cursor can move through the entire document using 'Right Arrow Key' alone.

Sub Temp()

'Select the first character in document
Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory

'Main loop starts here

'Move cursor 1 char to the right, while 'selecting' (Extend:=WdExtend
Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend

'Now you have 1 character selected. Insert your code here, whatever it is that you want to do with the selected text

'Now 'virtually' press Right Arrow to de-select
Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1

'Now repeat the main loop. Remember that this code snippet has no exit clause yet; with further coding it'll lock up your Word  ;)

'Happy progging!

End Sub